# Customizing html view to support image in android textview. Web view loads very slow in base64 image

Tags: android, nativescript

I want to use htmlview of nativescript to render base64encoded image. Is there any way to customize htmlview because there are lots of article that provide support for image in android textview and nativesccript htmlview is wrapped over android textview

i tried , used approaches provided for inserting base64 image via fromHtml method of android, but none worked. it displays [obj] instead of image

getSafe(text: string, view: any) {
    let context = view._context;

```
let d = new android.text.Html.ImageGetter({
  // @Override
  getDrawable(source: string): android.graphics.drawable.Drawable {
    let base_64_source: string = source.replace(/data.*base64/g, "");
    const data = android.util.Base64.decode(
      base_64_source,
      android.util.Base64.DEFAULT
    );
    const bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
      data,
      0,
      data.length
    );
    let image: android.graphics.drawable.Drawable = new android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable(
      context.getResources(),
      bitmap
    );
    image.setBounds(
      0,
      0,
      0 + image.getIntrinsicWidth(),
      0 + image.getIntrinsicHeight()
    );

    return image;

    // return new android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
  }
});
```

image is showing as [OBJ] and not image

Comment: Please share the complete code or possibly a Playground sample of the customised HtmlView.